How to fix bun.js failing to run tsc
bunx tsc --project tsconfig.json fails with the error
node_modules/@types/node/globals.d.ts:6:76 - error TS2792: Cannot find module 'undici-types'. Did you mean to set the 'moduleResolution' option to 'nodenext', or to add aliases to the 'paths' option?

... more of similar errors

I checked the source of the problem, and it looks conditional load, seems like globalThis is not defined.
...
type _Request = typeof globalThis extends { onmessage: any } ? {} : import("undici-types").Request;
...

How it could be fixed?
bun -v 1.1.16
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc --project tsconfig.json"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^5.5.2",
    "bun-types": "^1.1.16"
  },
  "dependencies": {
  }
}

tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "es2022",
    "lib": ["dom", "es2022"],
    "target": "es2022",
    "rootDir": ".",
  
    "outDir": "build",
  },
  "include": [
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}

typescript file
console.log("hi")

